# How to read password from file in IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, passwords

I am running Spring Boot application locally which require me to define `keystore.password` in `application.yml` file.

Normally I define password like

```
Keystore.password: "xxxyyyzzz"
```

It works perfectly fine. Problem is I don't want to keep password in `application.yml`.

I am just wondering if there is a way to read password from file store in local directory. Something like this:

```
Keystore.password: c:\password\password.txt
```

Or a way to set it up in IntelliJ so that it's available to every instance IntelliJ I am running on my machine.

Comment: Can you show what you've already done/tried?

Comment: I tried giving as file location but obviously didn't work, tried setting up in pwd file of intellij but no luck.

Comment: I meant in terms of code or sth. like that.

Comment: Just setting this property to speing Kafka config like. spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password: ${keystore.password}